# In what language was developed Adobe CS

Tags: adobe, system, platform

I want to know this, I believe is C++ & Windows .. but what you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know for sure, but having a look at :

http://stlab.adobe.com/

or

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/site/Home

might give you some hindsight about what kind of technologies Adobe may manipulate...

Another question around here may help you too :

[Experiences with Adobe's "Adam and Eve" C++ GUI library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657225/experiences-with-adobes-adam-and-eve-c-gui-library)