# GUI Frameworks for C++ Real world applications

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

C++ Applications have more performance than .NET so A lot of applications are written in C++.

But original C++ have no GUI support and thus Qt like frameworks help developers to develop Desktop GUI application However most of the applications are not QT applications as well.

**What are the most commonly used GUI frameworks/libraries for large, cross-platform C++ applications like Adobe Photoshop?  Is Qt common for larger applications?  If not, what are the advantages of using these libraries over more common cross-platform libraries like Qt?**

Comment: Very good question. I would like to know the answer too.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley I like to know what are the framworks(like qt) develop complex C++ Applications?

Comment: What is your question ? Do you want to know what GUI tool kit is used with Illustrator, Photoshop... ? or do you want to know if those applications are made with C++ ?

Comment: The OP is saying that most of the AAA-class applications (like PS or 3DMax) are not made with common frameworks that have goot interface support. So OP wants to know, how is the UI in such applications programmed (i.e. did the developers make their own libraries for it, or did they use plain WINAPI or something else).

Comment: @A.G. what QUI tool kit is used with illustrator,Photoshop also how they are written?

Comment: @A.G.: I believe OP is asking what GUI libraries are used, which should imply which language.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that these types of heavy-duty desktop applications are build on-top of their own (proprietary) GUI libraries. These are, in-turn, written on top of some low(ish)-level API like the ["Windows API"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) for example. I expect that Adobe and Autodesk develop this sort of thing in-house, in contrast to using some publicly available library (like Qt).

Comment: So Are they written completely Win API?

Comment: @unique: Obviously not the Mac versions.

Comment: Adobe uses ASL (Adobe Source Libraries) and the small description see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657225/experiences-with-adobes-adam-and-eve-c-gui-library and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Source_Libraries. The answer of biril is generally correct.

Comment: One cannot be sure, but the WinAPI is a safe bet considering that performance is critical in this type of app. Also note that some of these first went into development during the 90s when Win32 was the only available API. On the other hand, these types of applications tend to get very large so different parts often get developed by different teams using different methods. As for @BenjaminLindley's comment, yes, the WinAPI was just an example specific to Windows. It raises an interesting point though: A UI library may be developed on multiple platforms hiding specifics behind a common interface

Comment: MFC was introduced in 1992 so my comment "during the 90s when Win32 was the only available API" is obviously wrong. But you get the picture.

Comment: @biril. Now all this is officially called "Windows API". Saying Windows API "is a safe bet" :)

Comment: @SChepurin Yes, it's a bit redundant. I specifically meant, and should have stressed, *not* .NET and generally *not* some other UI library built on top of the Windows API.

Comment: @biril thanks finally i got the answer about Adobe